# docker compose именованные тома

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose, static

Немного не до конца понимаю, как правильно описывать тома для совместного использования между контейнерами

**Что имею:**

1. Контейнер с приложением фронта и запущенным Django (якорь elk_dm4_app) с помощью wsgi.py и gunicorn (структура директорий в контейнере ниже)

```
elk_dm4
├── backend
|   //Джанго приложение
│   ├── api
|   |   └── ...
|   ├── collectedstatic
|   |   └── ...
│   ├── elk_dm4
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── settings.py
|   |   ├── wsgi.py
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── index
|   |   └── ... 
│   ├── manage.py
└── frontend
    └── ...
```

2. Сервис для запуска `collectstatic` (docker-compose.yaml)

```
services:
...
  collectstatic:
    <<: *elk_dm4_app
    command: bash -c "python ./backend/manage.py collectstatic --no-input && python ./backend/manage.py createsuperuser"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - app
```

> Команда collectstatic собирает статические файлы в директорию `/elk_dm4/backend/collectedstatic`

3. Сервис nginx:

```
services:
...
  nginx:
    build: _docker/nginx
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - app
      - collectstatic
```

---

**Вопрос:**

Как сделать контейнеру с nginx видимой папку `/elk_dm4/backend/collectedstatic` из контейнера collectstatic?

Пробовал поиграться с именованными внутренними томами, но только запутался, либо получалось, что в контейнере nginx видна эта директория по странному адресу и без результатов collectstatic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общих чертах это работает предельно просто:

```yaml
version: "3.0"
volumes:
  # Объявляем том
  my_volume: {}

services:
  collectstatic:
    ...
    volumes:
      # монтируем том под сборку статики
      - my_volume:/elk_dm4/backend/collectedstatic
      #       что:куда
      
  nginx:
    ...
    volumes:
      # монтируем том под раздачу статики
      - my_volume:/var/www
```

В разделе `volumes` создается том, после чего этот том подсовывается в нужные места в контейнерах. Данные в томе обновляются без задержек (это по сути одна и та же директория), так что NGINX увидит файлы как только они там появятся. Как они будут раздаваться уже зависит от конфигурации NGINX.

Comment: Придётся ли тогда менять command у collectstatic?

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев не придется, если директория, куда собираются файлы не содержит ничего нужного. Монтирование заменит только последнюю директорию в пути.